# How do I add flutter_local_notifications to my app?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I wanna add notification in my app with `flutter_local_notifications` but once I add the plugin to my .yaml, my app doesn't run again. 
Below is the error

````
```D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel
````

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/18.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/20.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/22.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/25.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/26.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/27.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/28.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/30.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/31.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/33.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44.jar, /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/restaurant/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45.jar
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s

---

The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See ... for more information on the problem and how to fix it.

---

Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1```

Thanks.

Comment: Try to add "multiDexEnabled true" to your gradle file and change minSdkVersion to 21 Further information:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle

Answer (score 0):

First you need to upgrade all the packages that you have to the version where they are compatible with `AndroidX`. You can know that from the `ChangeLog.md` of each package on the [dart packages  page](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter). Next you need to open the android project of your flutter in `AndroidStudio`, then select `Refactor`->`Migrate to AndroidX`. Wait a bit until android studio refactors your project. And the run rebuild project from android studio. It should work then!